# Get package dependencies from NPM registry API

Tags: npm, npm-registry

Given a package name and version, I want to find out what its dependencies are, ideally using an HTTP request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sending a `GET` request to e.g. `https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-codes` or `https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-codes/0.0.2`. See the [API documentation](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md).